# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Two components with the same id

Tags: ajax, updatepanel, modalpopupextender, calendarextender, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm working in ASP .NET dynamic data.
In one of my edit controls I wanted to allow the user to add records from a related table to the current page. (Literally, if you are on the orders page, you would be allowed to add a new customer to the system on this page as well, and then associate it with that order).
So, I have a DetailsView set to InsertMode, nested inside of an UpdatePanel, which is shown by a ModalPopupExtender which is invoked when 'add new' is clicked.
This doohickey works the first time i execute this process, that is, a customer is added (and i update the dropdown list as well).
However, I realized it didn't work (properly) again until I refreshed the entire page.
When I attached my debugger, my worst fears were realized (ok, not really).  But an exception was being thrown: 
"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Two components with the same id." Which seemed to be complaining about a Calendar Extender Control that is part of the details view.

Any guidance on what's going on here would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: Haven't found a solution to this, but i'm currently looking at this: http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/06/masterdetail_with_the_gridview_1.html as a way of using jQuery as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at my popup control 
[A Popup Insert control for Dynamic Data](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2009/12/popup-insert-control-for-dynamic-data.html) I built it for just that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a search from a textbox and encountered this error after postback. `UpdateMode="Conditional"` on the `UpdatePanel` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I got The Solution,

add **ScriptMode="Release"**  in ScriptManager of Page like that

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="0" ScriptMode="Release"
        EnablePartialRendering="true" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```